# Can I mount wall 75 inches (50kg) tv on plasterboard?

Tags: drywall, walls, plaster, television, brackets

I am going to mount a TV to a wall in my living wall.
The only problem I have is the TV weighs about 50kg and I am little bit afraid of hanging this amount of weight on pure plasterboard.

Is it safe to do so?

TV i am trying to put on the wall:

- https://www.samsung.com/uk/tvs/qledtv-q9fn/QE75Q9FNATXXU/

The wall mount that I am planning to buy:

- https://www.samsung.com/uk/tv-accessories/no-gap-wall-mount-wmn-m22e/

I am aware of where the studs are.

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions here type    TV mount  into search bar for lots of reading

Comment: The TL;DR here is NO. I've not seen a mount yet that tells you you can reply solely on drywall to hold it up. If someone hits your TV it's probable to rip out of the drywall and fall (damaged TV and damaged wall)

Comment: You say you know where the studs are, but will the mount be located over any of them? Or is your intent to place the mount in between studs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can position the mount so you can attach to two studs, it will be fine.

If you can position the mount so you can attach to one stud, and use toggle bolts to attach the four corner holes of the mount, that will be fine too.

If you had only drywall to attach to, with toggles or other heavy duty supports, you might still be OK.  I couldn't assure it because it really depends on the condition of the drywall, framing, etc.  But for example these anchors

http://www.toggler.com/products/snaptoggle/tech_specs.php

are rated for over 100kg pounds shear strength in 1/2" drywall.  I'd use a bunch to be safe - I'd arrange them in a "W" pattern

[image: Samsung Mount]

And as I said, no guarantee, but I personally would be confident with this mount if the wall is well constructed and in good condition.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question I would say don't do it. But an easy solution is to determine the width of the studs in your wall and then get 3/4" plywood and cut a rectangular panel long enough so that you can securely fasten both ends into a stud inside the wall. Then you can securely attach your TV bracket into the 3/4" plywood and it should hold up well. Once I actually had 2x4's and cut them to be 17" long. I used 3" screws to secure them horizontally onto the wall attaching them to the studs that were spaced 16" in the wall. I made sure the horizontal studs were placed so that the screw holes of the TV bracket were centered in the horizontal studs I attached to the wall. If you do this correctly your TV is not going anywhere. This makes your television stick out a couple more inches but if you don't mind this you will have a very securely connected TV to your wall. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Adrien has the answer. 
When the studs don't line up with the mounting holes then do as he suggested.
However that said, if the builder of the house had intended this wall for a wall mount television they might have nailed in lots of 2x6  pieces between studs to provide the needed support. A stud finder should verify this.